# Geometry question about triangle and a circle

Tags: geometry

We have triangle $ABC$, and we construct a circle on side AC to become its diameter.
This circle contains the middle point of side $BC$ and intersects side $AB$ in point D, in ratio of $AD:DB=1:2$. 
If $AB$ is $3cm$ what is the area of triangle $ABC$?

My attempt: $CD$ seems to be the height of triangle(because it's at $90$ degrees), perpendicular to $AC$. I used that $CD=\sqrt{AD*DB}$.
So I have height and base of triangle which turned out that area is $3\sqrt{2}/2$, but solution seems to be $3\sqrt{2}$. Why?

Comment: Why do you think that $CD \perp AB$?

Comment: Is it not that triangle $ADC$ is a right triangle?

Comment: Why? Can you explain? I can't see any such thing.

Comment: Angle in a semicircle is always 90 degrees when one side is a diameter of a triangle.

Comment: I used Thales's theorem.

Comment: Yeah I see. Good point.

Comment: Another question $:$ How do you get $CD= \sqrt {AD \cdot DB}$? Which rule do you use here? Because I can see that it doesn't hold in general. For instance equilateral triangles are the good counter-examples.

Comment: What I got that the diameter of the circle should be $3.$ Hence the area of $\Delta ABC$ is $\frac 1 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \sqrt {3^2-1} = 3 \sqrt {2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

The angles $ADC$ and $AEC$ are right, because both subtend the diameter $AC$.

From $AD:BD=1:2$ and $AB=3$ we can find $AD=1$ and $BD=2$.

The line $AE$ is both height and median, it implies the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles. Hence, $AC=3$.

From the right triangle $ACD$ we can find $CD=\sqrt{AC^2-AD^2}=2\sqrt{2}$.

Finally, the area of the triangle $ABC$ is $\frac12 \cdot AB\cdot CD=\frac12 \cdot 3\cdot 2\sqrt{2}=3\sqrt{2}.$